# Download file without leaving page - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, download, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm trying to get a download link to work using google drive as the source.

Currently, I can get it to work by downloading it to a temp file, opening a new page and then downloading the file on the new page.

User controller

```
def download_file
  .....
  file = <get the file>
  file.download_to_file(Rails.root.join("tmp/#{file.title}"))
  send_data Rails.root.join("tmp/#{file.title}"),
    :type=>file.available_content_types.first,
    filename:file.title, :x_sendfile=>true
end
```

view

```
%td
 = link_to "Download", download_file_path(@user), target: "_blank"
```

At present this opens up a new page (makes a couple of error beeps) and then gives me a file.

Is there a slightly more elegant way (without js if possible) to

download from the same page both of them fail to download the file.
(tried a redirect_to :back to send back and remote:true but both fail).

Comment: If you are going to download one of the user's files, wouldn't it be better to get the export links from the file and use that link in the href property of the <a> tag? As far as I know, in this way, and since the user is already logged into the account, clicking on that link would start the download directly instead of asking the user to login into the account.  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#methods

Comment: I'm not actually using a users account. I'm using an account that's related to the server. What I specifically don't want to do is be accessing it through the interface from google drive. I'm doing something programatically with the file that isn't run through the interface.

Comment: oh, what i meant was to call the API function files.get(), and from the response you can get the DownloadURL or the exportLinks.  With those links, the user could just click and download the file. But in your case, as the file belongs to the application (i guess it belongs to the service account) you would have to make this file public or at least share it with the user.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically it. I was just looking for a way where I wouldn't have to download to a local temp file (as this is a bit of a pain on heroku). I guess that's the only solution. I'm going to modify the question as the real issue is that the download link itself makes weird error beeps and only works in certain circumstances.